# Android ImageView not loaded

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview

I am using the android imageView and I put the the image into the drawable folder, and changed the imageView source to that image. But it does not show the image in the Preview panel and when I open the picture in the android studio,it show the error like this.

[image]

But I can open the picture on my computer desktop. so why there is the error and how to solve it?

Comment: Show the code for the layout of that imageview

Comment: did you open your image with external program like AS says?

Comment: Close and restart the android studio...it might work for u

Comment: yeah! Now i have solved the problem. The problem is the png picture. the picture was not the png and i just changed the extention of the picture. i seam like the png picture but it is not the png. So i have saved the picture into the png style. then i got right.

Comment: thank you for your help. i have solved the problem but i do not the reason. why i only change the extention of the picture does not work. but when i save the picture into another png picture ,it works !

Comment: i am facing same problem

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like piac.png was not a .png file, you just slapped a .png extension on it and expected it to become a .png file.  The problem is likely resolved by opening the file (maybe it was a .jpg) and then saving it as an actual .png file.

Comment: Because simply changing a file's extension, does not not change the file's actual format.  Files must be converted to another format.  The easiest way is to just use a photo editor to change the format.

For example.  If you change file.whatever to file.png, that doesn't change the file's contents, it just changes the extension.  If you open file.whatever in a program that can read the files contents, you can then save (and hence convert) the file to another format.  Does that make sense?  If so, please give my answer a check mark.  Thanks.