# Image not loaded in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, file-upload, image-upload

I have downloaded the image but it isn't getting loaded in android studio.The image is saved as .png itself and I tried to load it while the file was open as well, how do I fix it? The error image is in the link below.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mOfZ.jpg

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797223/android-imageview-not-loaded)?

Comment: yes I've done everything that it says